# accessing scope variable from directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I made a directive to display a script tag in my view:

```
angular.module 'app'
.directive 'kwankoScript', ->
  restrict: 'E'
  replace: true
  template: '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ptag_params = {
    zone: "transaction",
    transactionId: "id",
    currency: "EUR",
    customerId: "' + scope.user.uuid + '",
    siteType: "d"
    };
    </script>'
```

I call this directive from my view `dashboard-validate.html` like so:

```
<kwanko-script></kwanko-script>
```

I can access `{{transaction.uuid}}` from the view, but I cannot from my directive.

I would like to replace `transactionId: "id"` by 
`transactionId: "{{transaction.uuid}}" but it doesn't work.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED :

this is my directive now:

```
 angular.module 'paycarApp'
.directive 'kwankoScript', ->

  restrict: 'E'
  replace: true
  scope: 
    transaction-id: "="
  template: '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ptag_params = {
    zone: "transaction",
    transactionId: {{ transaction-id }},
    currency: "EUR",
    customerId: "' + scope.user.uuid + '",
    siteType: "d"
    };
    </script>'
```

and my view:

```
 <kwanko-script transaction-id="{{transaction.uuid}}"></kwanko-script>
```

If I don't put the curly braces, the directive is not executed

and this is the output

```
 <script type="text/javascript" transaction-id="" class="ng-scope"> 
    window.ptag_params = { 
    zone: "transaction", 
    transactionId: {{ transaction-id }}, 
    currency: "EUR",
    customerId: "7514c32b-0aec-1b00-a52d-e676ff62e297",
    siteType: "d" };
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like that angular (/jqlite) cannot cope with script tags inside a template. It can however cope with it if you include jquery before angular

Comment: I've tried by replacing the script in the template by a simple `<div>` and that still doesn't work. can I maybe send you a direct message ?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/ynagdh2g/1/, with a div it works

Comment: indeed that works fine. If I try to pass `{{user.uuid}}` it doesn't work anymore. is there a reason for that ?

Comment: Yes I use on the scope `userId: "="`, which means it will allready evaluate the variable and therefore the `{{}}` aren't necessary anymore.

Comment: ok I got everything working with the div, I just need to get it to work with the script. can you develop a bit about including jquery before angular. at the moment, I do  `<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>`

Comment: It actually looks like it does work with you, because you said 'this is the output', and showed the output script

Comment: no it doesn't, when I have a template : `<div> {{transactionId}} </div>` I get the transactionId, but when I change it to the script tag, I see the string `{{ transactionId }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108911/discussion-between-mike-w-and-devqon).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `scope` variable for this in your directive, where you can define which properties you want to bind to your directive. Make your directive like this:

```
angular.module 'app'
    .directive 'kwankoScript', ->

    restrict: 'E'
    replace: true
    template: '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.ptag_params = {
        zone: "transaction",
        transactionId: {{ transactionId }},
        currency: "EUR",
        customerId: {{ userId }},
        siteType: "d"
        };
        </script>'
    scope: {
        transactionId: "=",
        userId: "="
    }
```

Then do in your view:

```
<kwanko-script user-id="user.uuid" transaction-id="transaction.uuid"></kwanko-script>
```

Comment: this doesn't evaluate {{ transaction-id }}   `<script type="text/javascript" transaction-id="" class="ng-scope"> window.ptag_params = { zone: "transaction", transactionId: {{ transaction-id }}, currency: "EUR", customerId: "undefined", siteType: "d" }; </script>`

Comment: Lose the `-id` and make it `transactionId` (camelcasing) in your template, like in my given code

Comment: It looks like that angular (/jqlite) cannot cope with script tags inside a template. It can however cope with it if you include jquery before angular

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass scope data from controller to the directive scope. Ideally the scope of controller and directive are not isolated and hence we just need to bind them
**In View > pass controller scope uuid to the directive as shown below**

```
<kwanko-script tid = "transaction.uuid"></kwanko-script>
```

**In JS code > We need to make the directive aware of how to make use of controller scope data**

```
app.directive 'kwankoScript', ->
  restrict: 'E'
  replace: true
  scope: {
         tid : '='
  }
  template: '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ptag_params = {
    zone: "transaction",
    transactionId: {{tid}},
    currency: "EUR",
    customerId: "' + scope.user.uuid + '",
    siteType: "d"
    };
    </script>'
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I've tried that already. I see `transactionId: {{tid}}`

Comment: Did you add the code
scope: {
         tid : '='
  }

inside the directive as shown above